# How to add a unique constraint using a column from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, unique-constraint

I have 3 tables in SQL Server 2008 R2 that look like these:

[image: DB Model]

A COMPANY may have many LSPs. An LSP may have many SERVICEs.

And I need to make sure that SERVICE_CODE uniquely identifies a SERVICE record within a COMPANY. In other words, COMPANY_ID + SERVICE_CODE should uniquely identify a SERVICE record in the entire system.

For example: COMPANY-A may NOT have 2 services (with 2 different SERVICE_IDs) with the same SERVICE_CODE. But COMPANY-A and COMPANY-B may both have 2 separate SERVICES (again, with different SERVICE_IDs) with SERVICE_CODE = "PREMIUM".

I need something like this:

```
alter table "SERVICE" 
add constraint "SERVICE_Index01" 
unique ("COMPANY_ID", "SERVICE_CODE")
```

But (obviously) this fails because the COMPANY_ID column is not in the SERVICE table.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is Service_Code unique? At first I thought Service_ID was a surrogate key for the natural key Service_Code. But if two companies can have different service IDs with a service code of 'Premium', this suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as an external constraint:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CompanyServices
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
  c.COMPANY_ID,
  s.SERVICE_CODE
FROM       dbo.COMPANY c
INNER JOIN dbo.LSP     l ON c.COMPANY_ID = l.COMPANY_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.SERVICE s ON l.LSP_ID     = s.LSP_ID
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_CompanyServices
ON dbo.CompanyServices (COMPANY_ID, SERVICE_CODE);
```

The index will make sure there's no duplicates of `(COMPANY_ID, SERVICE_CODE)` in your data.

Comment: This looks great! Thanks! I will try it today and let you know how it went.

Comment: Hi @AndriyM - I'm doubting between trying this or trying to enforce this in my app layer.  Do you know if there are any performance issues with this approach that might not scale well with hundreds of thousands of rows? (as the view needs to be updated every time when you do an insert I guess?)

Comment: @DirkBoer: You guess correctly, an indexed view is a materialised view, and changing underlying tables' contents necessarily triggers the view's update. I'm afraid I'm not in a good position to tell you when to start expecting serious lags caused by this kind of solution, but I certainly would expect them to happen at some point. My personal choice would be to start with this anyway. As a developer, I'm not a stranger to application-level constraints, and over time I've learnt to prefer using them only as the last resort.

Comment: @DirkBoer: To explain a little more, for me, data reliability usually ranks higher in the list of priorities than performance, and I find database constraints to be superior in that regard to application-level solutions. But that's "for me" and "usually", and your situation might require some other reasoning.

Comment: Good point @AndriyM! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is each company limited to a single LSP? Is Service_Code unique (or could there be two service codes "PREMIUM" with different Service_IDs)?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Company
(
  CompanyID INT PRIMARY KEY
  -- , ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.LSP
(
  LSPID      INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  CompanyID  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Company(CompanyID) -- UNIQUE?
  -- , ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Service
(
  ServiceID    INT PRIMARY KEY
  -- , ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.LSP_Service
(
  LSPID        INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.LSP(LSPID), 
  ServiceID    INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Service(ServiceID), 
  PRIMARY KEY (LSPID, ServiceID)
);
```

Comment: A COMPANY may have many LSPs. There could be 2 SERVICEs (with different IDs) with the same SERVICE_CODE as long as they belong to 2 different companies. I will update the example to make this clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add COMPANY_ID to service table.

If you need rows in Service table to be unique by this id it makes sense to keep a foreign key reference in this table.

Comment: That would be redundant, though, since Company_ID is already in the LSP table.

Comment: Thanks, but I am hopping there is a way to do this without changing any tables.

Comment: If you can't change any tables I don't think you can achieve your goal using a constraint because your tables aren't modeled quite right. You may have to resort to triggers, since not all business rules can be easily enforced using declarative constraints. I haven't spent enough time on this one to be 100% sure, but that's my initial impression.

Comment: So in order to make this work, I need redundant information stored in the SERVICE table? Like you said, the COMPANY_ID is already in the LSP table :-(

Comment: Hopefully, this isn't a very huge table and one extra number won't hurt a lot.